# Paypal integration issue in titanium

Tags: javascript, android, ios, paypal, titanium

I have to implement Paypal into my application. Here I have added some products into the cart. If I click the cart, I have to pay the amount using Paypal.

When clicking the Paypal button, I am getting the following error:

**The amounts specified for item price,tax,and shipping do not add up to the total amount.**

Why am getting this error?

I am using the following code:

```
$.paypalWindow.addEventListener('open', function(){ 
var Paypal = require('ti.paypal'); 
var u = Ti.Android != undefined ? 'dp' : 0; 
var status = Ti.UI.createLabel({ top: 20 + u, height: 50 + u, color: '#333', text: 'Loading, please wait...' }); 
$.paypalWindow.add(status); var price = totalamount; 
 var   invoiceitemslist = JSON.stringify(data);

var button; function addButtonToWindow() {
if (button) { $.paypalWindow.remove(button); button = null; } 
button = Paypal.createPaypalButton({ width: 194 + u, height: 37 + u,    buttonStyle: Paypal.BUTTON_194x37, top: 20 + u,

    language: 'en_US',
    appID: 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
    paypalEnvironment: Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_SANDBOX, 
    feePaidByReceiver: false,
    enableShipping: false,
    payment: { 
        paymentType: Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_BUSINESS,
        subtotal: price, 
        tax: 0.00,
        shipping: 0.00,
        currency: 'USD',
        recipient: 'thaibusiness@gmail.com',
        customID: 'anythingYouWant',
        invoiceItems:
    [{"name":"Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan","totalPrice":2997,"itemPrice":999,"itemCount":3},
          ],
        ipnUrl: 'http://www.appcelerator.com/',
        merchantName: 'EYMOBINS Insurance',
        memo: 'For the insurance with EYMOBINS!'
          }
        });

button.addEventListener('paymentCancelled', function (e) {
    alert('Payment cancelled. Please try again!');
    addButtonToWindow();
});
button.addEventListener('paymentSuccess', function (e) {
    alert('Payment successfull. Please get your Policy No.!'+"  "+e.transactionID);
    $.paypalWindow.remove(button);
    //addButtonToWindow();
});
button.addEventListener('paymentError', function (e) {
    alert('Payment Error. Please try again!');
    addButtonToWindow();
});

button.addEventListener('buttonDisplayed', function () {
    $.paypalWindow.remove(status);
    //alert('Please pay '+Ti.App.totalcost+'$ with Paypal!')
});

button.addEventListener('buttonError', function () {

});

 $.paypalWindow.add(button);
 } 
 addButtonToWindow();            
  });


 $.paypalWindow.open();
```

Please check the code and give me an idea to resolve the above issue.

**EDIT:**

Here I am facing one issue:

```
[{"name":"Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan","totalPrice":999,"itemPrice":999,"itemCount":1},{"name":"Average2Excellent CBSE KG EVS MATHS ENG Educational CD ROMS","totalPrice":547,"itemPrice":547,"itemCount":1}]
```

Here the totalamount is 1546. Here I have printed the invoiceitems in the console, and I am getting the data like above.

So that I have given like:

```
invoiceItems:invoiceitems,
```

Like means am getting the issue (the amounts specified for item price, tax, and shipping do not add up to the total amount).

Same thing I have written the code like:

```
invoiceItems:[{"name":"Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan","totalPrice":999,"itemPrice":999,"itemCount":1},{"name":"Average2Excellent CBSE KG EVS MATHS ENG Educational CD ROMS","totalPrice":547,"itemPrice":547,"itemCount":1}]
```

it's working perfectly.

It is not working dynamically when assigned the value. Can you please check the code and help?

**EDIT:**

**If i have tried to run this code on android device, as am clicking the paypal button nothing happends. Why the login form is not open in the android device.**

Comment: Can you provide the correlation id returned from the PayPal response ?

Comment: i didn't give the correlation id in my code anywhere.Where i have to create that id ? if you are having the tutorial please give me that for learning

Answer (score 5):

Why are you escaping the quotes in this code?

```
[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan&quot;,&quot;totalPrice&quot;:2997,&quot;itemPrice&quot;:999,&quot;itemCount&quot;:3}
```

This is not valid JSON (or Javascript for that matter). Is this required by Paypal? I think it should look like this:

```
[{"name":"Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan","totalPrice":2997,"itemPrice":999,"itemCount":3}
```

**Edit:**

I've had a closer look at your code sample. Can you confirm where `totatamount` is coming from? As the code sample stands it will be `undefined`, which would be consistent with the error message you have described. Can you confirm it is definitely the correct value IMMEDIATELY before you submit this data?

The ti.paypal spec has a nice code sample in the [README file](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.paypal/commit/8924eba1fd5d74ac888a953c47a85a714648fc8a), which gives a good example of how to setup `createPaypalButton`. I would recommend looking at this if you haven't already.

```
button = Paypal.createPaypalButton({
    // NOTE: height/width only determine the size of the view that the button is embedded in - the actual button size
    // is determined by the buttonStyle property!
    width: 194 + u, height: 37 + u,
    buttonStyle: Paypal.BUTTON_194x37, // The style & size of the button
    bottom: 50 + u,

    language: 'en_US',
    textStyle: Paypal.PAYPAL_TEXT_DONATE, // Causes the button's text to change from "Pay" to "Donate"

    appID: '<<<YOUR APP ID HERE>>>', // The appID issued by Paypal for your application; for testing, feel free to delete this property entirely.
    paypalEnvironment: Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_SANDBOX, // Sandbox, None or Live

    feePaidByReceiver: false, // This will only be applied when the transaction type is Personal
    enableShipping: false, // Whether or not to select/send shipping information

    advancedPayment: { // The payment itself
        payments: [
            {
                isPrimary: true, // Mark this as the primary vendor; this marks this as a chain payment.
                merchantName: 'Primary Vendor',
                paymentType: Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE, // The type of payment
                paymentSubtype: Paypal.PAYMENT_SUBTYPE_DONATIONS, // The subtype of the payment; you must be authorized for this by Paypal!
                subtotal: 13, // The total cost of the order, excluding tax and shipping
                tax: 0,
                shipping: 0,
                recipient: '<<<YOUR RECIPIENT HERE>>>',
                customID: 'anythingYouWant',
                invoiceItems: [
                    { name: 'Shoes', totalPrice: 8, itemPrice: 2, itemCount: 4 },
                    { name: 'Hats', totalPrice: 2, itemPrice: 0.5, itemCount: 4 },
                    { name: 'Coats', totalPrice: 3, itemPrice: 1, itemCount: 3 }
                ]
            },
            {
                merchantName: 'Vendor 1',
                paymentType: Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE, // The type of payment
                paymentSubtype: Paypal.PAYMENT_SUBTYPE_DONATIONS, // The subtype of the payment; you must be authorized for this by Paypal!
                subtotal: 10, // The total cost of the order, excluding tax and shipping
                tax: 0,
                shipping: 0,
                recipient: '<<<YOUR RECIPIENT HERE>>>',
                customID: 'anythingYouWant',
                invoiceItems: [
                    { name: 'Shoes', totalPrice: 8, itemPrice: 2, itemCount: 4 },
                    { name: 'Hats', totalPrice: 2, itemPrice: 0.5, itemCount: 4 }
                ]
            },
            {
                merchantName: 'Vendor 2',
                paymentType: Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE, // The type of payment
                paymentSubtype: Paypal.PAYMENT_SUBTYPE_DONATIONS, // The subtype of the payment; you must be authorized for this by Paypal!
                subtotal: 3, // The total cost of the order, excluding tax and shipping
                tax: 0,
                shipping: 0,
                recipient: '<<<YOUR RECIPIENT HERE>>>',
                customID: 'anythingYouWant',
                invoiceItems: [
                    { name: 'Coats', totalPrice: 3, itemPrice: 1, itemCount: 3 }
                ]
            }
        ],
        ipnUrl: 'http://www.appcelerator.com/',
        currency: 'USD',
        memo: 'For the orphans and widows in the world!'
    }
});
```

Comment: yes...now i have updated.am getting the same issue only

Comment: If i have tried to run this code on android device, as am clicking the paypal button nothing happends. Why the login form is not open in the android device.

Comment: Is it only on Android?

Comment: yes only i have facing these problem only in android...iphone it's redirecting to paypal login form

Comment: Does this module works with Ti SDK. 5.2.2 with Android API 22 and above?